# Fetching records one by one from PostgreSql DB

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

There's a DB that contains approximately 300-400 records. I can make a simple query for fetching 30 records like:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE isValidated = false
LIMIT 30
```

Some more words about content of DB table. There's a column named isValidated, that can (as you correctly guessed) take one of two values: true or false. After a query some of the records should be made validated (isValidated=true). It is approximately 5-6 records from each bunch of 30 records. Correspondingly after each query, I will fetch the records (isValidated=false) from previous query. In fact, I'll never get to the end of the table with such approach.

The validation process is made with Java + Hibernate. I'm new to Hibernate, so I use Criterion for making this simple query.

Is there any best practices for such task? The variant with adding a flag-field (that marks records which were fetched already) is inappropriate (over-engineering for this DB).
Maybe there's an opportunity to create some virtual table where records that were already processed will be stored or something like this. BTW, after all the records are processed, it is planned to start processing them again (it is possible, that some of them need to be validated).

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: It is some kind of essay writing please write to the point and understandable.

Comment: I fail to see the problem, get all(remember there isn't millions of them) the records - update thoose that needs updating. If needed, rinse-repeat. What am I missing?

Comment: Bhavik Ambani:
To the point: how to fetch specific number of records without repeats on already processed ones.

esej:
Some time later there could be thousands of such records, and getting them all will be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can imagine several solutions:

1. store everything in memory. You only have 400 records, and it could be a perfectly fine solution given this small number
2. use an order by clause (which you should do anyway) on a unique column (the PK, for example), store the ID of the last loaded record, and make sure the next query uses `where ID > :lastId`

Comment: @couling: PostgreSQL can handle large data sets quite nicely. All you need to do is to tell the JDBC driver to **not** load everything into memory.

Comment: Now it has 400 records, next week there'll be thousands of them (and, yes, the objects are heavy.
I don't quite understand the 2nd variant. Could you please clarify on this or provide some links? I think it is what I need.

Comment: First page: you get the 30 first non validated records ordered by ID: `select * from table where validated = false order by ID limit 30`. You remember the last ID: 47. Second page: you get the 30 first non validated records ordered by ID and where ID is bigger than 47: `select * from table where validated = false and ID > 47 order by ID limit 30`. You remember the last ID: 122. Etc. etc.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name good point, actually you have to do two things 1: turn off auto-commit `myConnection.setAutoCommit(false)` and 2: set the fetch size on the statement before running the query `query.setFetchSize(30)`.